# Looping to get all elements, where to utilize forEach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, mapping

I am doing web scraping to return the values, however I am not sure how to output all the elements.

For example the html would look like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="code" value="111">
<input type="radio" name="code" value="222">
<input type="radio" name="code" value="333">
```

I am trying to output all the values.

```
function scrapeValues {
const $codes = $('input[name="code"]');
    for (const code of $codes.get()) {
      const $code = $(code);
      const results = $code.val() as string;
      codeArray = results.trim();
    }
  return codeArray
}
```

Currently, I am only getting the last value (333). I am thinking I need to utilize forEach somewhere but I tried to use it after $codes.get() but I am getting errors, not sure if it is because the closing tags are in the wrong place or if I need to implement it elsewhere.

Comment: All of your elements have the same exact name soooo.... only one of them can be chosen... and you should grab the value of the one that was: .checked as in ... loop through the inputs and see if any of them is checked... if it is... grab that elements value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP wants to utilize [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) after having retrieved e.g. a `NodeList` via [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which one, before  the mapping, needs to make an [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Btw, [jquery implements its own `map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/#map-callback) ...

```js
console.log(
  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"][name="code"]')
  ).map(node => node.value)
);
console.log([
  ...document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"][name="code"]')
  ].map(node => node.value)
);

console.log(
  $('[type="radio"][name="code"]')
    .map(function () { return this.value; })
    .get()
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="code" value="111" />
<input type="radio" name="code" value="222" />
<input type="radio" name="code" value="333" />
```